Same schema on two different servers show different COST and (%CPU) in the Explain plan
We have two servers having duplicate schemas. We are seeing a difference in the COST and (%CPU).
Here are the plans:
For the first server (with 12 cores as it's a development environment):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |          |    13M|  2666M| 10791   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR      |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000 |    13M|  2666M| 10791   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          |    13M|  2666M| 10791   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| PERSON   |    13M|  2666M| 10791   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Note
-----
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 12 because of degree limit

For the 2nd server (with 64 cores as it's a production environment):
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |          |    13M|  2666M|    74  (25)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR              |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)        | :TQ10000 |    13M|  2666M|    74  (25)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    PX BLOCK ITERATOR         |          |    13M|  2666M|    74  (25)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| PERSON   |    13M|  2666M|    74  (25)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Note
-----
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 64 because of degree limit

Both are running same DB Version (19c).
Does the higher COST with lower %CPU (first server) perform better than lower COST and higher %CPU (2nd server)? What could be the reason for this and what is the more optimal plan?

It is normal for cost to differ from server to server. It incorporates various stats that will not be the same from one database to the next. You are safe to ignore COST - if Oracle gets it right, your SQL should be performing well. If it gets it wrong - then it's an incorrect estimate and should be ignored. In either case, the COST shown in the execution plan is of no use for query tuning.

The operation "TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL" implies that your production server is an Exadata system, and your development server is not. The Exadata system is using a Smart Scan to offload much of the work of retrieving and filtering results to the storage servers. The figurative and literal "cost" of a full table scan should be much less on an Exadata system. Since the Exadata server spends less time performing I/O, the percentage of total time spent on CPU is higher. This query should run significantly faster on the production Exadata server compared to the development server.
